# Re-execute a function to return different random number

Tags: jquery, function, variables, execute

I'm creating an addition and subtraction question generator. The user inputs a minimum value and a maximum value, and chooses either the 'addition', 'subtraction' or 'mixed' radio button. They then click submit and two numbers are randomly generated for addition or subtraction. I have an addition function and a subtraction function to determine the total, below:

```
function addition (a, b) {

  var result = parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10);

  return result;
}

function subtraction (a, b) {

  var result = parseInt(a,10) - parseInt(b,10);

  return result;
}
```

My problem is this: when they choose the 'mixed' radio button (to randomize between addition and subtraction) I can get it to randomly choose addition or subtraction, but can't get it to keep randomizing between the two.

I have a function to generate a random number between 1 and 10. (below):

```
function random_operation() {

var randOpMin = 1;
var randOpMax = 10;

var rand_operation = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randOpMax - randOpMin + 1)) + randOpMin;

return rand_operation;
}
```

...and a variable that runs the function on document load to determine the random number (below):

```
var operation_num = random_operation();
```

..If the number is below 5, then the total is the value of the subtraction() function, and if its above 4 then the total is the value of the addition function.

I need to be able to regenerate the random number when the user answers the question correctly or if they click the 'next' button (which skips the current question) so that the questions are a mixture of addition and subtraction.

I've searched endlessly and cannot think how i can achieve this, any comments that may even steer me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just need to call the same method again. `var rnd1 = random_operation(); var rnd2 = random_operation(); var rnd3 = random_operation();`

Answer (score 0):

```
// "randomly" pick operation
var operation = Math.random() < .5 ? '-' : '+';

if (operation === '-') {
  // use minus
} else {
  // use plus
}
```